# How to make cut copy paste Handlers using C#

Tags: c#, registry, copy-paste

I want to make my `Cut copy paste` handlers using C#. I am using `WindowsXP`.

**Example:**
If user presses(ctrl+C) or Copy command through right context menu. I want my application will open and do the task in place of Windows Copy window.

Because I want my own design for that.

I heard about using `Registry` I can do that but how I don't know?

Answer (score 0):

I think this [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) could have something useful to you.

Basically you should build a background application listening to global keyboard events (look at the link for an example). When a user press `CTRL-C/CTRL-V` just react opening your Copy Window.